# Using google maps api key in open source GitHub repository in Flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, api-key

I am developing an open source Google Maps project by Flutter and I do not want the GMS API to appear in my repo when I integrate with Google Maps. I don't know how I can use the variable in the .env file in my AppDelegate.swift and AndroidManifest.xml files.

My AndroidManifest.XML

```xml
<application
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
               android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>
</application>
```

AppDelegate.swift

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MY_API_KEY")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

I added a .env file on my path and I ignore it on .gitignore. Using this method, I could easily use it in my files of lib folder by [flutter_dotenv](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_dotenv) package.

Comment: you want to upload that project to github?

Comment: @MunsifAli yes, I want to upload this project to GitHub

Comment: try the following solution it will work on android.

Answer (score 0):

For android you can try this:

1. create a values `xml` file `keys.xml` add your key in this file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="google_map_api_key">Your Api Key</string>
</resources>
```

2. use it in `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```xml
     <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
       android:value="@string/google_map_api_key" />
```

and add `keys.xml` to [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file to ignore the tracking of this file in git repository.

add this in .gitignore file

```
# ignore keys.xml
/android/app/src/main/res/values/keys.xml
```